# Filemaker WebViewer borders

Tags: javascript, google-maps, filemaker

I'm using Filemaker WV to show a google map.
WV text contains some javascript code.

There is always a scroll bar on the right; when scrolling, you get a white part of the WV displaying a text "aesthetically displeasing" 
/* Java Script */

My question is: 
Is there a way to get it out ?

*
FM16Pro Adv - Windows 10

Comment: Disable "Display progress bar" and "Display status messages" in the web-viewer settings.

Comment: thanks, but nothing changes

Comment: In this case, you need to add webviewer code to your question. A screenshot of the problem would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to FullScreenmode. 
When activated (by default google map control), I get neither scroll bar nor 
/* javascript */ message.

I have to understand how to switch to fullscreen by default when loading page.